# Restrict the user while number of digits before the decimal is greater than 8 and greater than 2 after decimal

Tags: javascript

Allowed values
999
99.99
12345678.12

Not allowed 
123456789  —> need to restrict the user if the 9th character is digit it has to be only decimal.

Comment: eh... what? come again,

Comment: list of allowed values are like:
10

20.00

10203040.50

10203040

Not allowed value:
102030405.00

var x=number.value.split(".") // ["102030405", "00"]

x[0] should always be max of 8 digits and If the user try to enter any digit after 8 digits Input textbox should not allow.
After 8 digits If user  can enter only decimal then allow 2 digits after the decimal to enter(This is optional)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this function:

```
function isValidNumber(num) {
    if (!parseInt(num) || (num.toString().length >= 9 && (num.toString().indexOf('.') == -1 || num.toString().indexOf('.') >= 9))) {
        return false;
    }
     return !(num.toString().indexOf('.') >= 9);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mention the user and number of characters, so I assume you are looking to filter this input after each keypress. You can use the built in HTML5 number input attributes but they are tested onchange, which means they don't get tested until onblur.

The solution below ties into the oninput event so it is triggered with each keypress. We test for min and max, then convert the value to a string to test that there aren't too many decimal places. If there are you could trim it, but I just rounded it.

```js
var decimalInput = document.getElementById('decimal-input');

decimalInput.oninput = function() {
  let decimalValue = decimalInput.value;

  if (decimalValue < 0.01) {
    decimalValue = 0.01;
  }

  if (decimalValue > 99999999.99) {
    decimalValue = 99999999.99;
  }

  let decimalString = decimalValue + '',
    decimalPos = decimalString.lastIndexOf('.');
  console.log(decimalPos);

  if (decimalPos != -1 && decimalString.length - decimalPos > 2) {
    decimalValue = Number(decimalValue).toFixed(2);
  }

  decimalInput.value = decimalValue;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" max="99999999.99" min="0.01" step="0.01" name="decimal-input" id="decimal-input" />
```